# How to convert a logical address to a paging system

Tags: memory, paging

ive had a look around and I cant seem to find an answer or how to work out this question, its a tutorial question for my operating systems course and ive looked through the notes that come with the question and i cant get an answer along with looking at the Ritche and silberschatz OS books. the question asks:

Demonstrate using a diagram how a logical address consisting of 24 bits could be converted to a paging system where each page was 16Kbytes. How many pages would there be in this system?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43821491/how-to-convert-a-logical-address-to-a-paging-system "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Comment: I learned virtual memory from Silberschatz & Galvin. I can assure you that it contains exactly the information needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming byte addressable, 16k bytes requires 16k addresses, right?

16k is 2<sup>14</sup>.  That means you need 14 bits to represent the full range of possible addresses within a 16k page.

So, what you need to do with the 24-bit logical addresses is consider 14 of those 24 bits as ***within-the-page addresses*** and the remaining 10 bits of those 24 bits as ***page numbers***.

Usually this would be done by considering the lower (or least significant) 14 bits as the in-page addresses and the upper 10 bits as the page-number (*however many other schemes/configurations/definitions of separating out a set of 14 bits and set of 10 bits from 24 bits are possible*).

*TL;DR*  --  We need to recognize that 16k is 2<sup>14</sup>; then use the lower 14 bits to use as in-page address and use the upper 10 bits to designate the page-number.

> How many pages would there be in this system?

I'll leave this as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thank you, this was very helpful, Am i correct in then assuming that the page number of bits (2^10) then amounts to the number of pages in the system, giving a total of 1024 pages?